# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null on angular4

Tags: angular, primeng

Getting

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

on assigning the icon value by condition check.

```
<button (click)="detailsToggle=!detailsToggle;" pButton [icon]="detailsToggle ? 'fa-toggle-on' : 'fa-toggle-off' " type="button" label="Details" class="details"></button><span class="badge">{{details.length}}</span>
```

Works fine on angular2 after upgrade of angular4 and primeng2 facing the error.

If I remove icon property works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

upgrade your primeng latest version :

**versions :**

```
angular: 4.4.1
primeng: 4.2.1
```

**in html**

```
<button (click)="detailsToggle=!detailsToggle" pButton type="button" [icon]="detailsToggle ? 'fa-toggle-on': 'fa-toggle-off'" label="Click"></button>
```

Comment: Same issue after upgrade of primeng : 4.1.2